# SoundCloud's "resolve" API endpoint returns another song

Tags: http, get, soundcloud

This is weird but I found out this error in the resolve endpoint of SoundCloud's API. I want to resolve this track:

- URL: https://soundcloud.com/wearecourtship/sunroof
- ID: 320689319

If I try this GET: https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://soundcloud.com/wearecourtship/sunroof&client_id=CLIENT_ID it gives me a `302` with a redirect on this response:

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/4459232.json?client_id=CLIENT_ID

But this is not the requested track. This is another one: https://soundcloud.com/other-songs/sunroof

If I try this GET instead: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/320689319.json?client_id=CLIENT_ID it returns the correct track.

What goes wrong on this track?

Comment: Same issue here. All URLs are returning the wrong data, and some 404.

Comment: Yes I realized it's not just one track... quite all...

Comment: Here as well. I also noticed that the waveform pngs are wrong for some songs on their webpage. We will just have to wait for them to fix it. They might update their status page to acknowledge the problem / when it's fixed: http://status.soundcloud.com/

Comment: Well, hope they discovered this bug or read this topic

Comment: Seems to be working just fine again for me, hope you can say the same ;)

Comment: It works for me too, thanks all

Comment: You should be careful about posting your `client_id` – that's something you don't want others to be able to use!

Comment: I'll hide it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was an issue with the SoundCloud API, which has now been resolved.